# htaccess mysteries: Can Joomla site run without .htaccess?

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration, server, configuration, apache

I was trying to understand .htaccess file. I learned some directives and added them on my htaccess.txt file but things weren't going as I expected. To test whether I put the contents on right file, I rename the htaccess.txt file to .bak. But I am surprised to see that after this change, my site is still running.

I did remember the other day, I tried changing htaccess.txt to .htaccess and my site is getting 500 error. I didn't do anything after that but today my site can run without it. I then move the .htaccess file (which was manually created by me) to another folder, and my site is still working. Could it be cache? I changed to another browser and my mobile, the site is still working! Mystery to me!

Also, on my linux server, /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, there are these lines:

```
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

I think this means every folders of every sites on my server use .htaccess. However, on this linux server I have several different Joomla sites, and some of them are using htaccess.txt and the others .htaccess!! Another mystery to me! Why is this?

Comment: This question is cross posted to: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/96018/31686

Comment: http://www.htaccess-guide.com

Answer (score 2):

## What is .htaccess?

> .htaccess is a configuration file for use on web servers running the
>   Apache Web Server software. When a .htaccess file is placed in a
>   directory which is in turn 'loaded via the Apache Web Server', then
>   the .htaccess file is detected and executed by the Apache Web Server
>   software. These .htaccess files can be used to alter the configuration
>   of the Apache Web Server software to enable/disable additional
>   functionality and features that the Apache Web Server software has to
>   offer. These facilities include basic redirect functionality, for
>   instance if a 404 file not found error occurs, or for more advanced
>   functions such as content password protection or image hot link
>   prevention.
>
> http://www.htaccess-guide.com

**htaccess.txt** that is contained in the joomla installer **is not .htaccess** - it's only a sample that can be changed to .htaccess, written to work with Joomla. An htaccess.txt is not executed, or doing anything else, it's only a text (.txt) file.

Joomla can work without `.htaccess`, this is how it is working when first installed. But in order to enable **url rewriting** (setting in Global Configuration) so that you can rewrite the /`index.php` urls to those without it, Joomla requires the `mod_rewrite` and this special rewriting for the `index.php`, that is written and shipped with the core `htaccess.txt`. So in this case the `.htaccess` is required as Joomla relies on it, and that's when Joomla documentation asks to rename the `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess`, otherwise your urls will return 404.

`.htaccess` is very **useful** and **powerful**, as it allows **custom configuration** of the **apache webserver**. It can be used to optimize and enhance operations of the server according to the specific needs of a web application. From simple redirections, to file handling, speed enhancements, restrictions and security.

So although for Joomla and generally websites/ web applications the htaccess is optional, its power and the results you can achieve with it makes it a strong recommendation, if not a requirement.

More reading: http://www.askapache.com/category/htaccess/